# h1:hover is responding on the whole width, unable to link h1 and don't know how to target things individually

Tags: html, css

Sorry, probably not the best title ever. I'm having trouble with a few things in my code that I'm using to practice html/css.

- `h1:hover` is responding whenever I hover my cursor over anything at the same height as the h1 heading.
- I'm also having trouble linking it. See the code below.

  ```
  <a href="http://www.bing.com"></a><h1>Bing</h1>
  ```
- I'd also like to know how to target specific things in the HTML code via CSS. For example if I import an image in HTML using IMG how would I edit just that image in CSS?

*Thank you.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `h1` by default spans the entire width of the page. Try changing it to an `inline-block` element like so:

```
h1 {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Second, you need to put the `a` tag *inside* of your `h1` tag and put the text inside of the `a` in order for it to function as a link.

```
<h1><a href="http://www.bing.com">Bing</a></h1>
```

Third, in order to target specific `img` elements, you can assign them a `class` or and `id` and target the desired one. For example:

HTML

```
<img id="myImage" src="whatever.jpg"/>
```

CSS

```
#myImage {
    width: 250px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

H1 is a block element, so it spans across total width of the page. To limit this effect, you must apply it a fixed width, or "display:inline-block;"

For the second question, the right code is:

```
<a href="http://www.bing.com"><h1>Bing</h1></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your anchor should be inside your `h1`, then you can apply any hover changes to the anchor:

HTML:

```
<h1><a href="http://www.bing.com">Bing</a></h1>
```

CSS:

```
h1 > a:hover {
  color:#F00;
}
```